# Application of Green's Theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I know this is a really basic question, but I seem to be kind of rusty.

$C$ is the boundary of the circle $x^2+y^2=4$

$$\int_C y^3dx-x^3 dy = \int_A -3x^2-3y^2 dA= \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^2 -3 r^2 r dr d \theta = -12 \pi$$

Did I make a mistake? My book says it's $-24 \pi$

Comment: It should be $-24\pi$. You were fine until the very last equals sign. Maybe write out some more details to see exactly where the integration mistake is.

Comment: Got it. I didn't realize $2^4=16$ and not 8. Ridiculous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the last calculation is incorrect:

$$\int_0^2 -3r^2 rdr = -3 \int_0^2 r^3 dr = -\frac{3 r^4}{4} \Huge{\vert_{\small 0}^{\small 2}}$$

This is equal to $-12$.  So your integral is $\int_0^{2\pi} -12 d\theta = -24\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the usual notation for Green's Theorem,

$$
P(x,y) = y^3 \rightarrow \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} = 3y^2
\\
Q(x,y) = -x^3 \rightarrow \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} = -3x^2
$$

$$
\iint_D \left( \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} \right) \ dA = \iint_D \left( -3x^3 - 3y^2 \right) \ dA
\\
= -3 \iint_D \left( x^2 + y^2 \right) \ dA
$$

Remembering $dA = r \ dr \ d\theta$ in polar coordinates,

$$
= -3 \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2} r^3 \ dr \ d\theta
\\
= -6\pi \int_{0}^{2} r^3 \ dr
\\
= -6\pi \left( \frac{2^4}{4} \right)
\\
= -24\pi
$$